# Where are Django directories created?

Tags: python, django, directory

I installed Django 1.8.4 for Python 3.4 and whenever I type into the command prompt:

```
django-admin.py startproject newsite
```

a new window opens up in Python IDLE with the following inside of it:

```
#!C:\Python34\python.exe 
from django.core import management

if __name__ == "__main__":
    management.execute_from_command_line()
```

I know there is supposed to be a new directory with `manage.py` and `url.py` etc. inside of it but I can't find it. I opened up `C:\python34\Scripts` and there is no new directory.

I've also tried typing into the command prompt:

```
python C:\python34\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject newsite
```

and then nothing happens, no window or anything.

Comment: It will be created in your working directory. A Django site isn't a script, so you certainly shouldn't expect it to appear in `/Scripts`.

Comment: Right. It was actually created in `C:\Users\PC\newsite\newsite`. Is there a way to change where it is created?

Comment: ...change your working directory?! Alternatively, once it's created, you can move it wherever you like.

Comment: No i mean when I execute `django-admin startproject <project-name>` I don't know where it is created and I want to know where it is created.

Comment: It's created *in your working directory*. If you don't know what that means, go and find out! Or read [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#startproject-projectname-destination) - you can specify the destination if you want to.

Comment: I changed my cwd to a folder I made `C:\DjangoProjects` and when I create a new project it doesn't show up

Comment: Have you tried `pwd` to confirm that you are actually in that directory?

Comment: I was just creating it wrong. `python django-admin.py startproject newsite` opens a window but doesn't actually create a directory. I need to provide the path of `django-admin.py` to it.

Answer (score 1):

Per [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#startproject-projectname-destination) (emphasis mine):

> **`startproject <projectname> [destination]`**
>
> `django-admin startproject`
>
> Creates a Django project directory structure for the given project
>   name **in the current directory or the given destination**.
>
> By default, the new directory contains `manage.py` and a project
>   package (containing a `settings.py` and other files). See the template
>   source for details.
>
> If only the project name is given, both the project directory and
>   project package will be named `<projectname>` and the project
>   directory will be created in the current working directory.
>
> If the optional destination is provided, Django will use that existing
>   directory as the project directory, and create `manage.py` and the
>   project package within it. Use `.` to denote the current working
>   directory.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> django-admin startproject myproject /Users/jezdez/Code/myproject_repo
> ```

Comment: I can't run `startproject` without first typing `django-admin.py`

Comment: Noone said that you could.